# Can Network Analyzer measure Impedance, Conductance, Susceptance or is there a device that does all?

Tags: impedance, capacitance, vna, conductance

I want to measure the impedance, conductance and susceptance of a large metallic object (about the size of a boat), and I want to know if it is possible to measure using Network Analyzer. If yes, are there steps that I can follow to measure the impedance, conductance and susceptance.

Comment: The size of the object doesn't matter, what matters is that you have a (2 point) connection between which you can measure the impedance. Yes most network analyzers can measure impedance and show that as real and imaginary part or conductance, susceptance, whatever you like (one can be calculated from the other).

Comment: But you need to **understand** what the network analyzer shows you, Sam. For which frequency range do you care, here? To which degree of accuracy? To which end?

Answer (score 1):

Most analyzers are designed to analyze components or circuits in low power domain. Low power here means several 100W.

For example, it is not possible to measure the impedanz of a choke or transformer with huge (several kg) iron cores with these devices. These devices are not able to deliver sufficient current to exceed the remanence. The situation is similar for bigger capacitors. The devices are not providing more than 60V, so it is not possible to measure a 450V cap. In such cases it is necessary to apply a power source and measure the step-response.
It is recommended to start with an estimation about the expected values. This helps to design the setup for measurements. Have a look on the specification/ ratings of your analyzer.

Comment: It also depends on the impedance analyzer.  With some of them, with the correct external fixture(s), you can basically tell it that you are using it's internal signal to drive a amplifier.  After you tell it what the amps characteristics are, it will those in to consideration when it processes the return signal.  And while this method is less accurate(+/- 3%)  than an internal path, it's much more convenient than doing it manually.